# How do I run a Twincat program without PLC?

Tags: plc, twincat, structured-text

I am a beginner in Twincat and have been playing around with it. I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE1CU6EebvTCJCMIUOSWgMseMaW-2k5zH) playlist where this guy explain structured text and successfully runs a program on his system. However when I try to run on my system, I get error 0x1028. Then I read that I have to configure parallel port as IO port in Twincat - got no idea how to do this. Help please!

Comment: It would help if you also post the the error message which probably came with the error code. If there was no error message, try to google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to configure any parallell ports in TwinCAT 3 to run TwinCAT 3 software on your machine.

Not sure what 0x1028 means, but if you're running a 64-bit machine (which you these days most likely are doing) you need to enable Virtualization Technology Extensions (VT-x) in the BIOS of your computer. You also need to run the command `C:\TwinCAT\3.1\System\win8settick.bat` (as administrator from the CMD)

You could alternatively run TwinCAT in a virtual machine. How you achieve this is described here: https://alltwincat.com/2018/06/14/twincat-virtualization/