# Twincat Activate Configuration error 0x1028 - unable to activate

Tags: plc, twincat, twincat-ads

I am a beginner in Twincat and is trying to run a sample program on my system(not on target).
I did all the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590242/how-do-i-run-a-twincat-program-without-plc) and did get the system up and running my sample code once. However, when I tried to run it again after a system restart, I get an error message.

[image]

I tried creating a new empty solution and another one with test code, both of them throws the same error code. Also, when I click on the green Restart TwinCat system button, I get the following error.

[image]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable AMD-V in your BIOS.

The procedure is explained here:

https://youtu.be/P9uUgT8EhUM?t=1029
(This is done for an Intel system, while you seem to have an AMD system, but it's the same procedure).

Also make sure to run this file in CMD (as Administrator):

```
C:\TwinCAT\3.1\System\win8settick.bat
```

And then reboot your computer.

If this doesn't do the trick, then do core isolation and run your TwinCAT task on an isolated core. Maybe that was what you were doing before but not now? It's described quite well in this video: https://youtube.com/watch?v=q7iRvDuAOFQ

Comment: I double checked, and virtualization is indeed enabled in my system. Which is why I got confused with the error message.

Comment: Not sure it will help, but you can try to do core isolation and run your TwinCAT task on an isolated core. Maybe that was what you were doing before but not now? It's described quite well in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7iRvDuAOFQ

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! May be you can add it in the main answer so that I can accept it?